# My python code does not seem to recognize the modules I install with pip

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pycharm

So this code obviously needs a module called vhs to run. Its not my code, just trying to get someones vhs emulator to run.

```
from vhs import VHS
...
vhs = newVHS(lumaCompressionRate, lumaNoiseSigma, lumaNoiseMean, chromaCompressionRate, chromaNoiseIntensity, verticalBlur,horizontalBlur, borderSize)
#optional
vhs.generation = 3
```

problem is, it keeps giving "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vhs'" when I try to run it using the PyCharm editor.
It could very well be just in the wrong folder somewhere, but I have no idea where to go looking for it

Updated pip using the command prompt directly and tried both

```
pip install vhs
```

and

```
python -m pip install vhs
```

Same result

Comment: Do you have multple copies of Python installed?  it could be you installed VHS in the one used at command line but not the one that PyCharm is using.

Comment: @LhasaDad I dont think so, but is there any way to doublecheck?

Comment: @bad_coder unfortunatly no. Im download these modules from cmd, and I dont actually know where its exactly putting them, which makes that solution useless to me

Comment: Using CMD [use this with Python to find the environment where its being installed](https://superuser.com/questions/49104/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-an-executable-in-windows), set that in PyCharm.

Comment: @bad_coder and of course, "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."

Comment: The post I linked explains how to do it. Try reading it carefully.

Comment: @VoidSpider  try checking in pycharm which interpreter its using and also you can see the packages it thinks it has available and will let you add them:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/managing-packages-in-pycharm/

Answer (score 0):

Correct way like this:

```
py -m pip install pyvhs
```